# Passing value to parameterized constructor in UDF from pig script

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, apache-pig

I have a parameterized constructor in the UDFS.

```
public WordMapList(String filePath)
    {
        filePt=filePath;
    }
```

with the main method as :

```
package customudfs;
public class WordMapList extends EvalFunc<String> {

    String filePt;

    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
    // code for reading file
    }
```

my pig script contains the following code :

```
 DEFINE WordMapList customudfs.WordMapList('/hhh/xxx/yyy/zzz/wordMapFile.txt');
```

But when i try to run the script using the code

```
 exec wordMap.pig
```

it is giving the following error:

> [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script
>   failed to parse:  Failed to generate logical plan.
>   Nested exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate
>   'customudfs.WordMapList' with arguments 'null'

Answer (score 0):

You should paste the full log. This happens sometimes because a ClassNotFoundException missing the

```
register ....jar ;
```

but the complete stacktrace of the log with some luck will tell.